# A consequence of $\beta X\setminus X$ not being zero dimensional.

Tags: general-topology, compactification

Is it true that if $X$ is a zero dimensional locally compact Hausdorff topological space, then if $\beta X\setminus X$ is  zero dimensional then there is a continuous function from $X$ onto $[0, 1]$?

I tried to prove it but I'm having trouble. 
I am reading a survey and I *think* the author uses this "fact". If it's not true, I will edit this post with more info.

Edit: There was a typo in my question. What I really wanted to ask is the following:
Is it true that if $X$ is a zero dimensional locally compact Hausdorff topological space, then if $\beta X\setminus X$ is **not** zero dimensional then there is a continuous function from $X$ onto $[0, 1]$?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but what does the $\beta$ stands for? Also how is dimension defined for general topological spaces? As I said, maybe I am just missing something.

Comment: As $\mathbb{N}$ cannot be mapped onto $[0,1]$, there ought to be a hypothesis not satisfied by $X=\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @M.Winter $\beta X$ is standard notation for the [Stone–Čech compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification). A general topological space is [zero-dimensional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-dimensional_space) if the clopen sets form a base for the topology.

Comment: Please state what the author actually says. As it stands now, it's clearly false. So provide a link, or retype the statements here (which is preferable; links do die).

Comment: Consider a finite X.

Comment: @user254665 The remainder is then empty and $\dim(\emptyset) = -1$, not $0$.

Comment: Given that you have already accepted an answer to the original question, it would be better to undo your edits to this question and simply post a new one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you ask is not true. Consider X the first uncountable ordinal with the order topology.  It is a known fact that every continous real-valued function on X is eventually constant. This has two relevant consequences: the Stone-Cech remainder is a single point, hence zero-dimensional, and the range of every continuous real-valued function is countable.

Comment: Excellent. Another way to see that $\beta \omega_1=\omega_1+1$ is: For a Tychonoff spacw $X$: If $p_1,p_2$ are distinct members of $\beta X$ \ $X$ then there are open sets $U_1,U_2$  of $ \beta X$ whose closures in $\beta X$ are disjoint, with $p_1\in U_1$ and $p_2\in U_2.$ Then $Cl_X(X\cap U_1)$ and $Cl_X(X\cap U_2)$ are disjoint and non-compact.  But non-compact closed subsets of $\omega_1$ cannot be disjoint.